# See data from multiple tables depending on column name

Tags: sql, join

What I am trying to achieve is to get information from multiple tables based upon a column name and then narrow down from that result.

Something to this effect:

```
select 
    top 3 * 
from 
    (Select TABLE_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where column_name = 'modify_id')
where
    MODIFY_ID = 'MULVEYR' or 
    MODIFY_ID = 'MULVEYR2' and 
    MODIFY_DATE > '12/31/2013'
```

And if possible, not to return anything if it returns 0 results for that table. The number of tables that have that column is 188, which is why I need to get something automated and not write out or check each manually.

Ideal output :
Out of the 188 tables, lets say only 50 of them have the information I need (where clause), then I would only see the top 3 lines of those 50 tables and not the blank results for the remaining 133

Comment: Is this query is working ?

Comment: @JDeveloper No, gives me "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'."

Comment: So you have 188 tables that have similar structure and you want a query that works across all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read you right, you are trying to search all of your tables for the one's that have a particular column, and then return a few records from each of those tables. Here is a solution, but I warn you, it uses dynamic sql and cursors, so it is very slow.

```
Declare cur_TableList Cursor
  For
    Select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    Where COLUMN_NAME='modify_id';

Open cur_TableList
Fetch Next From cur_TableList
  Into @tblSchema, @tblName;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    Set @sqlStmt = N'Select Top 3 * From ' + @tblSchema + '.' + @tblName;
    Set @sqlStmt = @sqlStmt + ' where MODIFY_ID = ''MULVEYR'' or ';
    Set @sqlStmt = @sqlStmt + 'MODIFY_ID = ''MULVEYR2'' and ';
    Set @sqlStmt = @sqlStmt + 'MODIFY_DATE > ''12/31/2013'' ';

    Print @tblName;

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlStmt ;

    Fetch Next From cur_TableList
      Into @tblSchema, @tblName;
END

CLOSE cur_TableList;
DEALLOCATE cur_TableList;
```

Comment: that worked great, just the last bit if its possible... those tables that return nothing (0 rows effected), if they don't have to appear at all in the results window

Comment: I am sure you can add an IF EXISTS in their somewhere.

Comment: heh alright. Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :-

```
select top 3 x.* from 
(
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where column_name = 'modify_id'    
)x
```

Comment: That won't work (tried as well) as the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS returns the column information, not the table information, thus using where clause that's meant for the table is throwing an error.

Comment: From where you are getting these fields MODIFY_ID and MODIFY_DATE.

Comment: That returns just the SCHEMA information. The MODIFY_ID and MODIFY_DATE are within the tables that I am pulling from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA by TABLE_NAME as in my original post

Comment: You are using this query :- Select TABLE_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where column_name = 'modify_id' which will return only one column (i.e. TABLE_NAME).Then how you will get the other 2 columns MODIFY_ID and MODIFY_DATE.